# Count comma separated unique values in a string

Tags: r, string, unique

The first two columns of dataframe make a composite key and there's a column of type char which contains comma separated integers. My objective is to make a column which contains the count of unique integers in the string.
I know the approach of converting string to columns using str_split_fixed and then counting the unique values but due to the length of string a large number of columns are added and everything lags. Is there any other method?
The actual data set contains 500k rows and 53 columns.
Sample dataset :
df

```
c1      c2    c3  
aa      11   1,13,4,5,4,7,9    
bb      22   2,5,2,4,5,7,11,     
cc      33   11,14,3,1,    
dd      44   1,1,2,4,5,6,15,    
ee      55   4,3,3,1,14,17,
```

desired output:

```
c1        c2             c3             c4  
------ | ------   | ------          | -----   
aa     | 11       | 1,13,4,5,4,7,9  |  6    
------ | ------   | ------          | -----   
bb     | 22       | 2,5,2,4,5,7,11, |  5   
------ | ------   | ------          | -----   
cc     | 33       | 11,14,3,1,      |  4   
------ | ------   | ------          | -----   
dd     | 44       | 1,1,2,4,5,6,15, |  6       
------ | ------   | ------          | -----   
ee     | 55       | 4,3,3,1,7,17,7, |  5    
------ | ------   | ------          | -----
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `stri_extract` to extract all the numbers, then loop through the `list`, find the `length` of `unique` elements

```
library(stringi)
df1$Count <- sapply(stri_extract_all_regex(df1$col3, "[0-9]+"), 
                     function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Comment: and thank you! Didn't know about stri_extract_all_regex. Will research about it.

Comment: @ShubhangiSharma  Looks like your post got edited.  Thanks

Comment: @ShubhangiSharma , It is difficult to edit tables in SO, but I would suggest use `dput(dataframe)` to paste sample of your data, so that it is answered in best possible manner. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Using `strsplit` with `uniqueN` from the `data.table`-package:

```
df$c4 <- sapply(strsplit(df$c3,','), uniqueN)
```

which gives:

```
> df
  c1 c2              c3 c4
1 aa 11  1,13,4,5,4,7,9  6
2 bb 22 2,5,2,4,5,7,11,  5
3 cc 33      11,14,3,1,  4
4 dd 44 1,1,2,4,5,6,15,  6
5 ee 55  4,3,3,1,14,17,  5
```

NOTE: if `df$c3` is a factor-variable, wrap it in `as.character`: `sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$c3), ','), uniqueN)`

---

Another base R alternative for creating `df$c4`:

```
sapply(regmatches(df$c3, gregexpr('\\d+', df$c3)), function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

---

A `tidyverse` alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate_rows(c3) %>% 
  filter(c3 != '') %>% 
  group_by(c1) %>% 
  summarise(c4 = n_distinct(c3)) %>% 
  left_join(df, .)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your df as something like below:

```
df <- c("1,13,4,5,4,7,9,", "2,5,2,4,5,7,11,","11,14,3,1,4,"," 1,1,2,4,5,6,15,","4,6,3,3,1,14,17,14,")
df <- gsub("\\s+|,$","",df) ##Removal of unnecssary spaces and trailing commas
```

then you can do using **baseR** :

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(df,split=","),function(x)length(unique(x))))
```

The result would be something like:

```
[1] 6 5 5 6 6
```

Comment: Your result is slightly wrong because of trailing commas without numbers in some rows

Comment: Thanks @docendodiscimus got it , it is because of leading spaces added trimws in my solution. It is working okay it seems.