# Checking for number of items in a string in R

Tags: r, text, field

I have a very large csv file (1.4 million rows). It is supposed to have 22 fields and 21 commas in each row. It was created by taking quarterly text files and compiling them into one large text file so that I could import into SQL. In the past, one field was not in the file. I don't have the time to go row by row and check for this.

In R, is there a way to verify that each row has 22 fields or 21 commas? Below is a small sample data set. The possibly missing field is the 0 in the 10th slot.

```
32,01,01,01,01,01,000000,123,456,0,132,345,456,456,789,235,256,88,4,1,2,1
32,01,01,01,01,01,000001,123,456,0,132,345,456,456,789,235,256,88,5,1,2,1
```

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, edits made.

Comment: R will likely throw you an error if the column counts don't match for each row when you are reading the data into a data.frame. So it's sufficient to just do `dim(df)` to check the dimensions of your data.frame. Unless, you are talking about complete cases in every row, which doesn't count NAs. Do clarify which one you desire.

Comment: @useR, I think that I will try your first suggestion. There are no NA's or NULL's in this case. The 10th field would be a 1 or 0, if it exists.

Comment: also, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43930490/1305688) might be helpful.

Comment: Are you looking for something link `str_count()` in the stringr package?  You could use this to count the commas in each line.

Comment: @Dave2e, I am going to try your suggestion as well. This sounds like an exact fit for the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the base R function `count.fields` to do this:

```
count.fields(tmp, sep=",")
[1] 22 22
```

The input for this function is the name of a file or a connection. Below, I supplied a `textConnection`. For large files, you would probably want to feed this into `table`:

```
table(count.fields(tmp, sep=","))
```

Note that this can also be used to count the number of rows in a file using `length`, similar to the output of `wc -l` in the *nix OSs.

**data**

```
tmp <- textConnection(
"32,01,01,01,01,01,000000,123,456,0,132,345,456,456,789,235,256,88,4,1,2,1
32,01,01,01,01,01,000001,123,456,0,132,345,456,456,789,235,256,88,5,1,2,1"
)
```

Comment: Instead of "tmp", would i put something such as C:\Users\Whatever or simply the name of the file which is "industry"?

Comment: I am getting the following error

: unexpected symbol in "table(count.fields(Industry"

Comment: Error in count.fields(industry, ",") : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection

Comment: As I noted in my answer and as the help file (`?count.field`) mentions, the first argument is the name of a file or a connection. For you, perhaps this would be `"C:/Users/Whatever/myFile.csv"`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe

```
apply(df, 1, length)
```

This will give you the length of each row.